# How to transform this recursive function into an iterative one?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, recursion, functional-programming

```
F = function(node){
    return typeof(node)!="object" ? 
               node
           : transformable([F(node[0]),F(node[1])]) ? 
               F(transform(F(node[0]),F(node[1]))) 
           : node;
};
```

This function receives a binary tree such as `[1,[[2,3],[4,5]]]` and applies a series of transformations recursively. Is there a way to convert that function so that

1. it receives, instead, a flattened binary tree such as `[N,1,N,N,2,3,N,4,5]`;
2. it does not use recursion?

Comment: I think you mean "iterative"

Comment: It also seems to do some fixpoint calculations :-)

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by iterative. If you mean solving it with loops it's possible but you need a backtrack stack that pretty much would mirror you call stack in the current recursive implementation so in practice it's still recursion, only with different stack.

You can only do pure iterative stuff without a stack if you don't branch. I.e. only one recursive call per tail. Trees have two or more so they can only be dealt with recursively.